# How do I iterate in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What's wrong with this Ruby code? I'm trying to solve [the first Project Euler question](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1).

I think the problem is in the syntax of `sum += num`, but I can't figure out what the proper syntax for this would be.

```
sum = 0
num = 0
num2 = 0

loop do
  num += 1
  if num % 3 == 0
    sum += num
    break if num > 1000
  end
end

loop do
  num2 += 1
  if num2 % 5 == 0
    sum += num2
    break if num2 > 1000
  end
end

puts sum
```

Comment: Are there any numbers that you might be counting twice?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. It is valid Ruby code.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative:

```
(1...1000).select { |x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 }.reduce(:+)
```

Comment: Why did you put `&:+` inside the `reduce`? I've always seen it done with `:+`.

Comment: See here: http://blog.thoughtfolder.com/2008-02-25-a-detailed-explanation-of-ruby-s-symbol-to-proc.html.

Comment: Well, yes, I knew what it does, but why not just use `:+` instead of `&:+`? It's shorter, easier to understand, and it removes and unnecessary call to `to_proc`.

Comment: You are probably right. Force of habit actually. Doing too many User.all.map(&:name). :X. I'll edit my answer for better clarity. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, just wondering since Ruby isn't really my main language :P

Answer (score 3):

You are making this *way* more complicated than it needs to be. Also, if the number is a multiple of 3 **and** 5, it gets added twice. Try something like this:

```
sum = 0 # initialize the sum
(1...1000).each { |x| # loop from 1 to 1000
    sum += x if x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 # add the number to the sum if it is
                                         # divisible by 3 or 5
}
puts sum # output the sum
```

Answer (score 0):

This runs, your syntax is okay, but does not give the right answer because, as mentioned, you add multiples of both 3 and 5 twice, once in the first loop, with `num`, and the second loop, with `num2`.

So you have two loops, but you actually only need one.

You only need to consider each number once, you can check it to see if it is a multiple of either 3 or 5. This will solve your double-counting issue and also make your code more concise.

Also, like Doorknob shows, the `each` syntax would save you some lines on those loops. You could also use the `for` syntax:

```
for num in (1..1000)
  <stuff here>
end
```

Check out the kinds of loops in "[Loops: How to do thousands of operations with a few lines of code.](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/loops/)".